# What's the deal with big number faulty arithematic in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, ecmascript-2016

So, I found something I couldn't understand and can't find any internet resource that explains it.

Please see the code below:

```
var num = 35422484817926290

// subtract 5 from num
console.log(num-5)
```

> Output (Wrong) : 35422484817926284

I checked it in Node, Opera, and Chrome, all of them give the wrong answers.

I do understand the fact that arithmetic with unsafe Integers in JS is faulty, for example:

```
console.log(100000000000000005-1)
```

> Output (Wrong) : 100000000000000000

So what's the deal with big number arithmetic in JS?

Comment: any integer bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is not going to work well, that's what `BigInt` is for - if you think xxx66e+307 + xxx22e+307 = xxx87e+307 is correct, then you have more problems than big numbers - hint: 66+22 = 88

Comment: Bug reports in JS - well, first, you have to know which JS engine you're talking about - then report it as appropriate

Comment: "*I do understand the fact that arithmetic with unsafe Integers is faulty*" - well, do you? And no, it's not just JS.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code:

```
var num = 35422484817926290

// subtract 5 from num
console.log(num-5)
```

in Visual Studio Code, i get the following warning:
"Numeric literals with absolute values equal to 2^53 or greater are too large to be represented accurately as integers."

So the correct way to make this calculation would be like this:

```
var num = 35422484817926290n

// subtract 5 from num
console.log(num-5n)
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not faulty, this is how the Floating point arithmetic works. Looks duplicate to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/3794205). For better calculation involving floating-point numbers you should use [BigNumber API](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/).

[image: Chrome Console]

Comment: or `100000000000000005n-1n` for modern javascript - no library required

Comment: @Bravo But this will not work with fractions

Comment: Sure, good point - but the question has no division and never dealing with anything but integers :p